# Reading only one "message" from a pipe each time?

Tags: multithreading, unix, io, pipe

I have two processes connected with a pipe.

One process has several threads writing messages on the pipe.

The other process reads the pipe and process the messages.

The problem is that, when the process reads the pipe, it gets all the messages one after another. ¿Is there any way of reading just one message at a time?

At first I used the write and read functions, using the file descriptors directly.
Then I tried treating them as files, using fdopen, fread and fwrite, but it still reads all the data at the same time.

The message's size can change each time, so I can't fix it by reading a fixed amount of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a long time ago, in a time before POSIX was a known concept anywhere in the world, at least one version of Unix maintained things such that writes less than the size of the space left in the pipe buffer were read in atomic chunks corresponding to the size of the packets written to the pipe, subject to the constraint that you tried to read enough data.  Unfortunately (or maybe I mean 'obviously'), I can no longer prove that this was the case — I've not had access to the relevant hardware and O/S for over a quarter of a century.

However, proof by counter-example demonstrates that Mac OS X no longer handles the reading side like that (though POSIX does guarantee that [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) calls are atomic if the requested sizes written are small enough).  This was something of a surprise to me.

#### Counter-example — code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

static void childish(int fd)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int  nbytes;
    int  pid = getpid();
    while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        printf("%.5d: %.4d <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

static void parental(int fd)
{
    char message[] = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog";
    int  pid = getpid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int  nbytes = rand() % (sizeof(message) - 1);
        while (nbytes == 0)
            nbytes = rand() % (sizeof(message) - 1);
        if (write(fd, message, nbytes) != nbytes)
            break;
        printf("%.5d: %.4d <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, message);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork\n");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        childish(fd[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        parental(fd[1]);
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;  // Failed to fork
}
```

#### Counter-example — data

Tested on Mac OS X 10.8.3.

```
86504: 0043 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Do>>
86504: 0001 <<T>>
86504: 0033 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over T>>
86504: 0006 <<The Qu>>
86504: 0030 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Ove>>
86504: 0036 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The >>
86504: 0024 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jump>>
86504: 0022 <<The Quick Brown Fox Ju>>
86504: 0031 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over>>
86504: 0037 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The L>>
86504: 0028 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped O>>
86504: 0017 <<The Quick Brown F>>
86504: 0032 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over >>
86504: 0038 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The La>>
86504: 0019 <<The Quick Brown Fox>>
86504: 0007 <<The Qui>>
86504: 0023 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jum>>
86504: 0005 <<The Q>>
86504: 0020 <<The Quick Brown Fox >>
86504: 0004 <<The >>
86504: exiting
86505: 0456 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy DoTThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over TThe QuThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped OveThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The The Quick Brown Fox JumpThe Quick Brown Fox JuThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped OverThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The LThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped OThe Quick Brown FThe Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The LaThe Quick Brown FoxThe QuiThe Quick Brown Fox JumThe QThe Quick Brown Fox The >>
86505: exiting
```

---

#### Atomic Writing — Non-Atomic Reading

This code uses `writev()` to write both a message length and the message to the pipe.  Of necessity, it uses two reads to get the data, fetching the length and then the message.  This works with a single reader; with multiple readers, you'd have to coordinate between the readers so that the file descriptor was not accessed by one reader while another had read the length but not read the data.  The code uses the [`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html) system call to write the length and the data in a single system call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void childish(int fd)
{
    int  nbytes;
    int  pid = getpid();
    while (read(fd, &nbytes, sizeof(nbytes)) == sizeof(nbytes))
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        int  actual;
        if ((actual = read(fd, buffer, nbytes)) != nbytes)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: short read (wanted %d, actual %d)\n", pid, nbytes, actual);
            break;
        }
        printf("%.5d: %.4d <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

static void parental(int fd)
{
    char message[] = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog";
    int nbytes = 0;
    struct iovec req[2];
    req[0].iov_base = &nbytes;
    req[0].iov_len  = sizeof(nbytes);
    req[1].iov_base = message;
    req[1].iov_len  = 0;
    int  pid = getpid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            nbytes = rand() % (sizeof(message) - 1);
        } while (nbytes == 0);
        req[1].iov_len = nbytes;
        if (writev(fd, req, 2) != (int)(nbytes + sizeof(nbytes)))
            break;
        printf("%.5d: %.4d <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, message);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork\n");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        childish(fd[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        parental(fd[1]);
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;  // Failed to fork
}
```

#### Example Output

```
86798: 0043 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Do>>
86798: 0001 <<T>>
86798: 0033 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over T>>
86798: 0006 <<The Qu>>
86798: 0030 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Ove>>
86798: 0036 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The >>
86798: 0024 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jump>>
86798: 0022 <<The Quick Brown Fox Ju>>
86798: 0031 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over>>
86798: 0037 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The L>>
86798: 0028 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped O>>
86798: 0017 <<The Quick Brown F>>
86798: 0032 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over >>
86798: 0038 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The La>>
86798: 0019 <<The Quick Brown Fox>>
86798: 0007 <<The Qui>>
86798: 0023 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jum>>
86798: 0005 <<The Q>>
86798: 0020 <<The Quick Brown Fox >>
86798: 0004 <<The >>
86798: exiting
86799: 0043 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Do>>
86799: 0001 <<T>>
86799: 0033 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over T>>
86799: 0006 <<The Qu>>
86799: 0030 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Ove>>
86799: 0036 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The >>
86799: 0024 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jump>>
86799: 0022 <<The Quick Brown Fox Ju>>
86799: 0031 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over>>
86799: 0037 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The L>>
86799: 0028 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped O>>
86799: 0017 <<The Quick Brown F>>
86799: 0032 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over >>
86799: 0038 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The La>>
86799: 0019 <<The Quick Brown Fox>>
86799: 0007 <<The Qui>>
86799: 0023 <<The Quick Brown Fox Jum>>
86799: 0005 <<The Q>>
86799: 0020 <<The Quick Brown Fox >>
86799: 0004 <<The >>
86799: exiting
```

I'm disappointed that the processes run strictly consecutively in this example; since this is multi-core machine, it was not what I expected.  When I changed the loop limit from 20 to 2000, then I got interleaved execution and the data stayed in synchrony on send and receive side.

I used 4-byte `int` values for the length.  Clearly, for the data on hand, it would have been sufficient to use a 1-byte `unsigned char` (heck, it could even be a `signed char` since the string is only 44 characters long).

Note that I've not seeded the `rand()` generator, so the output is deterministic apart from the process IDs each time it is run.

Note, too, that I'm not absolutely certain from reading the POSIX specification that the `writev()` segments are guaranteed to be treated as a single unit on the pipe.  If that's not the case, then you'll need to manufacture a buffer in the `parental()` code that contains the length followed by the relevant amount of data, and fall back on the plain `write()` call.  This is not at all hard to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void childish(int fd)
{
    char nbytes;
    int  pid = getpid();
    while (read(fd, &nbytes, sizeof(nbytes)) == sizeof(nbytes))
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        int  actual;
        if ((actual = read(fd, buffer, nbytes)) != nbytes)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: short read (wanted %d, actual %d)\n", pid, nbytes, actual);
            break;
        }
        printf("%.5d: %.4d <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

static void parental(int fd)
{
    char message[] = "\000The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog";
    int  pid = getpid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int nbytes;
        do
        {
            nbytes = rand() % (sizeof(message) - 1);
        } while (nbytes == 0);
        message[0] = nbytes;
        if (write(fd, message, nbytes + 1) != (nbytes + 1))
            break;
        printf("%.5d: %.4d <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, message+1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork\n");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        childish(fd[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        parental(fd[1]);
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;  // Failed to fork
}
```

#### Adding threading to the writing code

Creating threads to do the writing is not all that hard.  The code still uses `rand()`, but `rand()` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, so it may not be as good as you'd like.  On the other hand, this code is simply using `rand()` to generate variable sized messages; it is not critical that it perform perfectly.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void childish(int fd)
{
    char nbytes;
    int  pid = getpid();
    while (read(fd, &nbytes, sizeof(nbytes)) == sizeof(nbytes))
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        int  actual;
        if ((actual = read(fd, buffer, nbytes)) != nbytes)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: short read (wanted %d, actual %d)\n", pid, nbytes, actual);
            break;
        }
        printf("%.5d: %.4d R <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: exiting\n", pid);
    exit(0);
}

static void *p_thread(void *data)
{
    int fd = *(int *)data;
    char message[] = "\000The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog";
    int  pid = getpid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int nbytes;
        do
        {
            nbytes = rand() % (sizeof(message) - 1);
        } while (nbytes == 0);
        message[0] = nbytes;
        if (write(fd, message, nbytes + 1) != (nbytes + 1))
            break;
        printf("%.5d: %.4d W <<%.*s>>\n", pid, nbytes, nbytes, message+1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("%.5d: thread exiting\n", pid);
    return(0);
}

static void parental(int fd)
{
    enum { NUM_THREADS = 3 };
    pthread_t thr[NUM_THREADS];
    int  pid = getpid();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&thr[i], 0, p_thread, (void *)&fd) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: failed to create thread number %d\n", pid, i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(thr[i], 0) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%.5d: failed to join thread number %d\n", pid, i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    printf("%.5d: master thread exiting\n", pid);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void)
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork\n");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        childish(fd[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        parental(fd[1]);
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;  // Failed to fork
}
```

Note that `p_thread()`, the thread function, is almost a copy of the previous `parental` function, but the new `parental()` function coordinates the creation and termination of three threads.  The code in `childish()` and `main()` did not need changing at all (though I added the `R` to the print in `childish()` to match the `W` in the code in `p_thread()`).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I didn't know about the writev system call, and I can't believe I didn't think of sending the size of the message before the actual message.